# Using plt.quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh, vector-space

How to use matplotlib arrow or quiver with a list like the following:

```
#X, Y, U, V
data = np.array([[1, 2, 0.5, 1],
                 [2, 3, 1, 1.5],
                 [3, 4, 1.5, 1.75],
                 [4, 5, 2, 2],
                 [5, 6, 2.5, 2.5],
                 [6, 8, 3, 3],
                 [7, 9, 3.5, 3.5],
                 [8, 20, 4, 4],
                 [9, 2, 4, 4.5]])

X = data[:, 0]
Y = data[:, 1]
U = data[:, 2]
V = data[:, 3]
```

The aim is to draw arrows from (X,Y) to (U,V) in the same frame with Xlim, Ylim = (30,30).

The examples I see on the internet, use a mesh grid for quiver. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you found don't use meshgrid as a grid, but for elementwise plotting. No matter which shape the arrays have, the elements at the same positions belong together.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
plt.title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')

#X, Y, U, V
data = np.array([[1, 2, 0.5, 1],
                 [2, 3, 1, 1.5],
                 [3, 4, 1.5, 1.75],
                 [4, 5, 2, 2],
                 [5, 6, 2.5, 2.5],
                 [6, 8, 3, 3],
                 [7, 9, 3.5, 3.5],
                 [8, 20, 4, 4],
                 [9, 2, 4, 4.5]])

X = data[:, 0]
Y = data[:, 1]

# If you want to plot vectors starting at X,Y with components U,V
U = data[:, 2]
V = data[:, 3]

# If you want to plot vectors starting at X,Y and ending at U,V
U = data[:, 2] - X
V = data[:, 3] - Y

Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')

plt.xlim(0, 30)
plt.ylim(0, 30)

plt.show()
```

Next time please provide your code in a usable format.

Comment: Note that this doesn't do quite what the question asks: the question wanted to plot arrows from `(X,Y)` to `(U,V)`. This solution will plot arrows at `(X,Y)` with the length of the vectors being `(U,V)`. I guess its unclear from the question exactly which behaviour is desired.